# How does the change of load on the Rx side influence the Tx resonance voltage in a wireless powering sysytem

Tags: passive-networks, wireless-charging

[image]

As the circuit shows, U = 5V toggling the polarity in 10KHz. When IL is changed from less than 1mA to 20mA, the P-P voltage of the Tx coil will increase. How should I understand the phenomenon? I have guessed that the increase of IL will only decrease the voltage on the Rx side.

Comment: You understand it by using a sim tool like micro-cap or LTSpice and modelling it. Quite simply your primary tuned circuit may become more resonant at the expence of the secondary circuit resonance.

Comment: If it helps, see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367990/wpc-communication-modulation).

Comment: Some operating point is changing, and the resonance or energy storage also changes, affecting the losses.