# Simulation of a class E power oscillator using LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, oscillator, simulation, ltspice

My goal is to understand and design a class E power oscillator. To this end, I am trying simulate the following schematic using LTSpice. Circuit topology and the design values are extracted from the paper "[from here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1440636/)" -

design specifications used in the paper are; 
Pout =1W, Supply =4.5V, frequency 800kHz, RL=50ohm, QL=13, efficiency =90%
 Objective of this question is not to understand the paper, but to understand why my repeat simulations does not work - of course, I believe that the circuit should work fine with their values. But to make the question clearer, in this paper, the circuit is modeled using its equivalent impedance sections (assuming only the fundamental harmonic) and the component values are calculated by using class E design equations for 0.5 duty. Few things to note: In their analysis, the the gate-to-source impedance of the MOSFET, Zgs  was measured at 800 kHz and used for the analytical equations, and voltage divider is experimentally tuned to obtain 0.5 duty.

(differences from the original paper are 1. make R2 170k -> 150k because it was not producing the oscillation when R2=170k, 2. zener diode model was not given in the paper)

[image]

However, I the oscillation waveforms are follows. Which include Drain Voltage - V(D); Gate voltage - V(G), Voltage across RL - V(RL+) and supply current - I(V1)
[image]

**What could be the reason for this oscillator not working as expected?** 
(It is expected to deliver approximately 1W power to RL, but here it is only few milliwatts)

**Alternatively, can someone suggest any other reference (preferably open access) to design a class E power oscillator close tho the same design specs?**

Comment: You can only view the original if you are an IEEE member. Are you wishing answers to be restricted to those people? Mark the nodes you measured on your schematic too.

Comment: Looks like the first job is to find the LF resonance and kill it. What does the paper say about L3 and Cgs/Cgd?

Comment: Andy if you copy the IEEE title, you can locate elsewhere (sometimes)

Comment: Pojj what do you understand about component Q selection and Conduction angle in Class E?

Comment: C3 and Cbp are uselss. If you want them to be active, impose `4.5 Rser=10m` (for example) in V1. Better yet, make it `4.5 Rser=10m Cpar=1u`.

Comment: Whenever I see  paper with reactive parts that use 4 digit values, I expect the design to overlook many sources of error.  This osc must have enough gm or gain to overcome the C ratio attenuator. You have a 71kHz Osc. I wonder what your layout looks like

Comment: @ Brian Drummond, I tried increasing Lc1, but it didn't help, when Lc1 is 10mH, supply current ripple reduces to ~1mA, but low LF resonance is still there. What can I do to get rid off this LF

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, To my understanding, Q selection must consider harmonic rejection and  resonance losses, and conduction angle of class E should be zero (MOSFET act as a switch in ZVS and ZdVS regions). oscillation frequency supposed to be at 800kHz and 71kHz oscillation seems to be from a LF resonance which I could not identify. I do not have a experimental layout yet, just trying out initial simulations

Comment: Do you understand why it doesn’t work well from my comment above? If not read until you do

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, It is difficult to digest you point, may be because my background is not so strong. But I noticed when I increase feedback ratio (by decreasing C32 to 20n), the circuit was oscillating - so the gain from the amplifier stage was not high enough to satisfy Barkhausen condition?. But I could not get your [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374845/simulation-of-a-class-e-power-oscillator-using-ltspice/374868?noredirect=1#comment907394_374868) on 71kHz and 11th harmonic? What LC combinations create secondary resonance?

Comment: The switch conducts into C1 strongly dropping the voltage and shunting L1 current then relaxes while L1 continues to supply current from the dropped voltage. THus the loop injects inductance and shunts C1 capacitance altering the loop resonance frequency when conducting .  When releasing switch  then current flows thru C1 in the opposite direction as Vds rises with L1 being a current source and the loop now has a higher loop BPF resonance or peak gain at 800kHz or so.  THis is the action of a CLass E Injection Locked Loop.   Monitor Ids with a current probe in sim and alter beta or RdsOn and R

Comment: L1 current I(V1) is actually resonating but the impedance of FET switch and its current spectrum is quite different .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the inductors are showing the dot, that's usually if there is some coupling (unless manually shown). Here's my attempt, no coupling:

[image: osc]

and some details for the waveforms as in your example. Note that `V(x)` is `V(RL+)`, and I used parasitics for the supply, which means the current through it incorporates what would have been your capacitors (if you had some resistance between the supply and the caps, as per the [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374845/simulation-of-a-class-e-power-oscillator-using-ltspice#comment907308_374845)):

[image: details]

Comment: Thanks, Now I have a working circuit for further study. But when I used mosfet model MTP3055 (downloaded from [link](http://espice.ugr.es/espice/src/modelos_subckt/spice_complete/POWMOS2.LIB)), it was still not oscillating.  not sure if it is due to the parasitic or issue with the model - anyway, it doesn't matter much now. Roger your comment. Next is to go one step further into efficiency analysis!

Comment: There is a much better topology and do you have any efficiency target?

Comment: @Pojj Those are subcircuits (i.e. more involved models), so I can't tell you what's wrong or not, I simply used a `.model` from LTspice's database. But I'd advise using different MOSFETs, even IRF has made newer, better ones than those, they're pretty ancient.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, yes, my target is achieve >90% efficiency at a low feedback ratio and  C32 is a variable cap. Would you suggest the better topology, please?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, do you think [IPN50R650CE](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/500v-900v-coolmos-n-channel-power-mosfet/500v-coolmos-n-channel-power-mosfet/ipn50r650ce/) is a good option? I am looking for a higher power MOSFETs as I want to increase the power level to 5W - 10W. Do you have any recommendation? -I am still understanding the topology operation- so, first, looking for a suitable MOSFET with a working simulation model.

Comment: @Pojj For this setup, it looks like a 100~300mOhm Rdson would be the choice, the gate charge is not so much of concern. If you want higher power, then raising Rdson is not a sensible choice. Also, the Vds seems too high, since the drain voltage is ~3x the supply (maybe higher with different topologies), but the current is what you're after, for power. You could easily make an olscillator with kV on the drain, but almost no current. Power needs current, so lower Rdson, but not too low or it may damp the oscillations, instead.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, This is a masterpiece advice that I was looking for. Will keep it in mind. How about input and output capacitances? Should I look for low values?

Comment: Look at secondary/primary resonance harmonic ratio and impedance if RdsOn* duty cycle <50Ohms You have a pulse harmonic injection locked loop with unnecessary feedback LC. You were getting 71KHz fundamental instead of 11th harmonic making primary tuning too critical. I would use a series FET rather than a shunt FET

Comment: @Pojj The MOSFET capacitances come into play when choosing the values for the inductances and capacitances. Small or large, they'll influence mostly numerically, since you don't have here hard switching to account for transtion losses. Still, you don't want them too high (e.g. too many nF, or even tens of nF), since those will account for dissipation. And too low (hundreds or tens of pF) will cause fewer losses, but probably generate higher values for Ls and smaller for Cs, thus higher Q, thus higher instability (analog elements do suffer from it). In short, difficult to say.

Comment: Even the DCR of the L1 coil comes into play.