# LC oscillator emitter current doesnt go to 0(class C)

Tags: rf, bjt, oscillator, passive-networks

Im trying to create a 433MHz oscillator with the help of ADS for the simulation. From the lectures i have had on transistor LC oscillators, i know the are forced into class C operation, and that current in the emitter should look like this:
[image: Emitter current]

With a nice flat 0mA current in between the peaks.

In my simulation though, it doesn't really reach near 0mA current:

[image: ie2]

It actually looks like a sinus..

How come? Do i bias the base too much? I have tried to tune it a little, and i can come closer what i believe it should look like, but then there is some high frequency oscillations in between.

[image: ie3]

(could be worse/more oscillations in between)

Could it be some capacitance in the BJT that oscillates with the inductor?

This is the schematic:

[image]

Comment: try mine http://tinyurl.com/ybgfgopw

Comment: Did you mean [Class E](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/374845/95619), by any chance?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: That definitely looks like what i believed it should, although the frequency is alot smaller. Im not sure what the 25nF cap from the emitter to ground does?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: I have not heard of Class E before, but it kind of looks like there is always current flow in the BJT, as in my case. Is class E better for more power handling? Like driving 50 ohm

Comment: @Linkyyy Here's [something](http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/ee242/pdf/eecs242_class_EF_PAs.pdf) that might give you more clues.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: Thats interesting. Thanks. Do you have any comment on why my design does not look like class C? Do i bias it too hard? I've designed it for at specific current to make sure the FT is high enough

Comment: If your 1st pic is the one with what you expect to see as `Ic` you'll see that there are peaks of current starting from zero; this means high-frequency content. The 2nd pic shows a sine with no zero values, while in the 3rd, you'll notice that the change in bias seems to get you closer to the 1st pic. That is, the current seems to recede downwards. I suspect that whatever you changed is a step forward. Why stop there since you are in a simulator?